# Preload is not supported by Mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, optimization, preload

I have issue in preload, I tired to preload the css sheet using preload in html. Its supported by google chrome but its not supporting in firefox

```
<head>
    <link href=assets/css/master.css rel=preload onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" as="style" type="text/css">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
        as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" as="style" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel=preload
        onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" as="style" type="text/css">

    <link rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed href=images/favicon-apple-touch.png> <link rel=icon href=assets/img/logo.png
        sizes=32x32>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script" rel=preload onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" as="style">
</head>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### apparently it landed in firefox 85 on january 26th of 2021 according to caniuse

<strike>soon™</strike> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1222633

https://caniuse.com/#search=preload

<strike>as of right now, you can **only** enable preloading manually by enabling the `network.preload` flag in firefox.</strike>

edit in September 2020:
still in development: https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#link-rel-preload

Comment: Sorry to tell u i dont get ur point. can u plz share any links regarding with network.preload flag

Comment: OP wants to preload on the client, not his own browser.

Comment: @AlfredWallace the client is the browser. unless the feature is in stable, there is no way around telling users to enable the flag or fallback to conventional loading time. that's also exactly what i wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[It is slated to be enabled by default with the release of Firefox 79](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features#HTML) [on 2020-07-28](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Calendar).

Comment: Still not enabled in release 79…

Comment: not even in 80.. why did firefox become the new IE in terms of feature adaption..